# Excel Total Count

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I want total time consumed of below C column for respective tasks placed in column A and column B consisting of corresponding time

[image]

Comment: You want to use SUMIF, or a pivot table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enter the formula in cell `F2` , and drag down,

```
=SUMIF(A:A,E2,B:B)
```

Format the F column to `hh:mm` format to get the desired result. You can do this by selecting column F and pressing `Ctrl + 1`, and select the format.

Formula in cell `F5`,

```
=SUM(F2:F4)
```

Note:- Cell `E2` in your image is `Meetings` which should actually be `Meeting`, for this formula to work. You cannot have a different word in column E and a different word in column A.

Comment: @Jake thats great!!